# Can I make this media query work in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, media-queries

i'm trying to get my site to know when it's above 1096 to execute some CSS styling, here is my code

```
var mq = window.matchMedia('@media all and (max-width: 1096px)');
if(mq.matches) {
    window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName("sticky-leaderboard-ad-container")[0].setAttribute("style","padding-top: 4rem !important; margin-left: 0 !important");
}
```

please can someone let me know why this isn't working? thank you in advance

edit: i can't use CSS, it must be in javascript

Comment: It should instead be `min-width: 1096px`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript to do that.

You can use only css media queries to accomplish the same behavior like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1096px)
.sticky-leaderboard-ad-container {
     padding-top: 4rem !important; 
     margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

But, if you want to use javascript you can get the window width like this:

```
if(window.innerWidth < 1096) {
        let element = document.getElementsByClassName("sticky-leaderboard-ad-container")[0];
        element.setAttribute("style","padding-top: 4rem !important; margin-left: 0 !important");
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I can't use CSS for this unfortunately, has to be Javascript (I should have said)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your media respond when the screen size above 1096, you should instead use `min-width: 1096px`. `max-width: 1096px` captures when the screen is lower or equal to the target size.

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1096px)").matches) {
  /* The viewport is less than, or equal to, 1096px pixels wide */
} else {
  /* The viewport is greater than 1096px pixels wide */
}
```

or:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1096px)").matches) {
  /* The viewport is greater than, or equal to, 1096px pixels wide */
} else {
  /* The viewport is less than 1096px pixels wide */
}
```

Besides `window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName()` doesn't make sense, change it to `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 0):

You could create an event listener and make use of the window object to get the viewport dimensions.

```
window.innerWidth 
window.innerHeight
window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1096px)")
```

[matchMedia docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)